# To get empty array

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code but i met a some strange thing.

```js
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
  let count = 0;
  let positive = 0;
  let negative = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] < 0) {
      negative += input[i];
    }
    if (input[i] > 0) {
      count++;
      positive = count;
    }
    if (input == 0) {
      return [];
    }
  }
  return [positive, negative];
}

console.log(countPositivesSumNegatives([0, 0]));
```

Why output is [0, 0] instead of []  ?
I'm trying to get just empty array []

Output has to be:

countPositivesSumNegatives([1, 2, 3, -1, -3]) -> [3, -4]

countPositivesSumNegatives([0, 0]) -> []

Comment: Can you explain *why* you think it should be `[]`?

Comment: `input` is an array, so `input == 0` is never going to be true. Is this just a typo and you forgot to type `input[i] == 0`?? Really, basic debugging can answer this question for you...

Comment: probably you want this before the for loop: if (input.length === 0) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time you return `[]` is when the condition `(input[i] == 0)` matches on any element.

However, given the name of the function you only want to *skip* such elements.

If and only if the argument contains no other elements but `0`, return the empty array.

So the following modified code will work:

```js
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
  let count = 0;
  let positive = 0;
  let negative = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] < 0) {
      negative += input[i];
    }
    if (input[i] > 0) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  positive = count; // Hoisted out of the loop. Unless your function contains more code, you do not need the 'count' variable at all.

  let seen_nonzero = ((positive !== 0) || (negative !== 0));
      // Flags whether a non-0 element is  present in your input.

  let a_r = 
      seen_nonzero 
          ? [positive, negative]
          : []
  ;
  return a_r
}

console.log(countPositivesSumNegatives([0, 0]));
console.log(countPositivesSumNegatives([1, 2, 3, -1, -3]));
console.log(countPositivesSumNegatives([-1, -2, 0, 1, 2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

**(UPDATED)**

Since the function should return `[]` only if all elements are `== 0`, you can check at the end of the loop if `positive` and `negative` are `== 0`, meaning no positive numbers have been counted and no negative numbers have been summed:

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
  let count = 0;
  let positive = 0;
  let negative = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] < 0) {
      negative += input[i];
    }
    if (input[i] > 0) {
      count++;
      positive = count;
    }
  }

  if (positive === 0 && negative === 0) {
    return [];
  }
  else {
    return [positive, negative];
  }
}

console.log(countPositivesSumNegatives([0, 0]));
```

Comment: no, because for example console.log(countPositivesSumNegatives([5, 7, 0, -2, -8])); also will be []

Comment: [] have to be if only countPositivesSumNegatives([0, 0]) or countPositivesSumNegatives([0]) or just many 00000 there...

Comment: I edit explanation